# Python syntax check equivalent to perl -cw

Tags: python, syntax, warnings

I'm trying to find a way to check the syntax (and warning also) in python the same way it's done on perl for example: `perl -cw filename.pl`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want one of:

- [PyChecker](http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/)
- [pyflakes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes/)
- [pylint](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylint)